# GDB: setting complex break point with condition involving variable from previous frame

Tags: gdb

Is it possible to set a complex breakpoint which has condition which involves check on the argument passed to the outer function(frame).

eg.

```
  1 #0  sample::_processMessage (this=0xa5c8c0, data=0x7fffe5ae31db "\027w\270ß¸\023\032\212\v", line=0x7fffe4799db8 "224.4.2.197:60200", should_process=true) a sample.cpp:426
  2 #1  0x00007ffff682f05d in sample::_process (this=0xa5c8c0, should_process=true, line=0x7fffe4799db8 "224.4.2.197:60200", data=0x7fffe5ae31db "\027w\270ß¸\023\032\212\v", sn=31824) a sample.cpp:390
  3 #2  0x00007ffff6836744 in sample::drain (this=0xa5c8c0, force=true) at sample.cpp:2284
  4 #3  0x00007ffff682ed81 in sample::process (this=0xa5c8c0, mdData=0x7fffe67914e0) at sample.cpp:354
```

Here I want to set a break point on sample.cpp:356,which is on in the function process-frame#3, 
if the _process or frame #1 at the time hitting breakpoint has sn == 31824

so actually break point is at function _process but I want pause the execution in the function process

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6):

I don't know if it's possible to create conditional breakpoints that reference an outer frame, but you could use breakpoint commands to achieve a similar result.

Here's an example gdb session:

```
(gdb) break some-location
(gdb) commands
Type commands for breakpoint(s) 1, one per line.
End with a line saying just "end".
>silent
>up
>if (sn != 31824)
 >continue
 >end
>end
```

Now every time `gdb` hits the breakpoint it will automatically move up a frame, check `sn` and continue if the value is not correct.  This will not be any (or much) slower than a conditional breakpoint, and the only real downside is that it will print out a line each time the breakpoint is hit, even if gdb then continues.

The `silent` in the command list cuts down on some of the normal output that is produced when a breakpoint is hit, this can be removed to get a more verbose experience.

Comment: This solution works ok, but hits the `next` problem -- if you try to `next` over this breakpoint, and it decides to continue, then your `next` won't stop, instead the program will run freely.  You can fix this, and make the condition depend on a variable elsewhere, by doing more of the scripting in Python.

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished with a gdb convenience function implemented in python:

```
import gdb


class CallerVar(gdb.Function):
    """Return the value of a calling function's variable.

    Usage: $_caller_var (NAME [, NUMBER-OF-FRAMES [, DEFAULT-VALUE]])

    Arguments:

      NAME: The name of the variable.

      NUMBER-OF-FRAMES: How many stack frames to traverse back from the currently
        selected frame to compare with.
        The default is 1.

      DEFAULT-VALUE: Return value if the variable can't be found.
        The default is 0.

    Returns:
      The value of the variable in the specified frame, DEFAULT-VALUE if the
      variable can't be found."""

    def __init__(self):
        super(CallerVar, self).__init__("_caller_var")

    def invoke(self, name, nframes=1, defvalue=0):
        if nframes < 0:
            raise ValueError("nframes must be >= 0")
        frame = gdb.selected_frame()
        while nframes > 0:
            frame = frame.older()
            if frame is None:
                return defvalue
            nframes = nframes - 1
        try:
            return frame.read_var(name.string())
        except:
            return defvalue


CallerVar()
```

It can be used like:

```
(gdb) b sample.cpp:356 if $_caller_var("sn",2)==31824
```